# Anomaly in my RecyclerView item adding code

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I got 3 types of items I want to add to my RecyclerView, a button (item with a button inside of it), a dummy (item with empty display), a normal item (item with some stuff inside of it).

I'm going to write a scenario that describes the adding/remove process when it should work but it isn't for some reason.

Scenario:

-add a button + dummy to RecyclerView, they get displayed just fine.

```
 WidgetItem dummy = new WidgetItem(true);
 arrayList.add(0, dummy);
 ca.notifyItemInserted(0);//ca is my adapter

 WidgetItem btnHolder = new WidgetItem();
 btnHolder.setButton(true);
 arrayList.add(0, btnHolder);
 ca.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

-add another normal item + 2 dummies -->fine

```
 if (nbrItems % 3 == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        WidgetItem dummy = new WidgetItem(true);
        dummy.setTilte("dummy" + i);
        arrayList.add(0, dummy);
        ca.notifyItemInserted(0);
      }
    }
 arrayList.add(0, wItem);
 ca.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

-remove 1 dummy + add a normal item -->fine

```
 if ((nbrDummy == 3)||(nbrDummy == 2))
      for (int i = 0; !foundDummy; i++) {
        if (cii.get(i).getDummy()) {
          arrayList.remove(i);
          ca.notifyItemRemoved(i);
          foundDummy = true;
        }

      }
 arrayList.add(0, wItem);
 ca.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

-remove 1 dummy + add a normal item (the same as above) -->not fine

This's when the problem happens and instead of getting a 3rd 'normal item' i get another dummy instead in the display.

What confused me was that the "onCreateViewHolder" method in my custom adapter didn't even get called at this step while it got called just fine in the previous ones.
Even if the item that just got displayed was a dummy the "onCreateViewHolder" method should execute at least like how it should.

But the code just skipped right to the "onBindViewHolder" method.

I'm suspecting that maybe something happened after the deletion of that dummy but then again why it worked fine in the code above.

I tried "notifyItemRangeChanged" after deleting the dummy but the whole recyclerView got messed up.

So yeah, what's going on here?

Comment: lets see your adapter class for your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Little messy but it should do for now
https://gist.github.com/T0uch-M3/949504326becad15fa6376c7dee35f5d

Comment: The item detection in "onCreateViewHolder" shouldn't matter now, as long the code inside get executed, when my problem is that it doesn't even get in

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change the list item layout based on the "type" of item, but you are doing so in `onCreateViewHolder`. The proper way is to use `onBindViewHolder` for that task

Comment: I understand that I may not be doing things as they should be here (I'm new to android dev) but then again the code was working fine till that step which is just the same to the one before it.

Comment: the reason it works until the last case is because of how a recycler view works. `onCreateViewHolder` is only called when a new (never before used) view is diplayed on screen. Once a view holder is created, it is saved in memory and any time this item comes into view,  `onBindViewHolder` will be called. [Please see Figure 9 in this example](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-recyclerview-33fd4ff9988e) to see what I mean. Notice how `onCreateViewHolder` is called once for a list item, but when a list item disappears and reappears, it only calls `onBindviewHolder`

Comment: I see what you mean, didn't know about this, I will try to come back to you as soon as I change my code respectively.

Comment: i should clarify that `onCreateViewHolder` is only called x amount of times, where x is the number of list items your screen can display. So if your list item was 200px in height with a total phone screen height of 800px, `onCreateviewHolder` would be called approx. around 4-5 times total

Comment: I did the count and my screen should display around 12 at once when the problem I'm getting is at 5th or 4th item, and about what you said earlier, I don't think I reused anything at the step when I removed an item and added another.
It's a logical explanation for how the code skipped the "onCreateViewHolder" but still can't relate to it.

Comment: I tried adding items without removing/adding dummies and they stacked just fine and even went passed the 10th item.

Comment: Uhm... You created two `ViewHolders` (`ItemViewHolder` and `FooterViewHolder`) but you are only using one `ItemViewHolder`. This results to your code being really messy with all those `if else statements`. That is also most probably the reason for your bug. I would advise you to cleanup your code, implement a `recyclerview` properly and repeat your scenarios.

Comment: The code is messy indeed, but i'm keeping track of every semicolon there don't worry, cleaning it up is already in my schedule too. And i already figured out where the problem was thnx mate.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to how RecyclerView works I suppose.

After I delete an item from the list and create another, the same old back item that I deleted come back instead.

So after trying a couple of things i found out that putting   *recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();* between the items deletion and the creation code solved my problem.